# Rails version changes regarding tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

I've been going through some good (seeming) resources for Rails tutorials, and will dutifully follow the steps until halfway through I realize a helper has been dropped or something else has changed. Aside from the 1.0->2.0 change (which I imagine was significant, given typical versioning), are there other updates that have fundamentally changed how rails works, and before which I shouldn't try to "translate" older resources? Thanks!

(please don't just say "read the changelog". I don't know how Rails works; it doesn't mean much to me yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say there have been any really big fundamental changes since Rails 2 where it was like, "OK, throw out the old tutorials." There have been some useful features added that might not be in older 2.x tutorials ([`named_scope`](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-has-finder-functionality) is the biggest thing that immediately springs to mind), but it's just another useful tool you can learn, not something that makes everything you've learned before useless.

Comment: Would you say that pre 2.0 documents are really different? There seemed to be such a flurry of "Let's Learn Rails!" when it was released, but a total newb is having trouble finding things that still -work-...

Comment: A lot is the same, but enough has changed that I think it might be a little bit confusing sometimes. At any rate, there's lots of info out there on Rails 2. All the stuff at rubyonrails.org/documentation, Railscasts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a list of changes to 'Edge Rails', http://ryandaigle.com/tags/Edge%20Rails

Hopefully that'll give you a better idea.